# How turn off page header on print in Chrome Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, printing

I would like to print documents from webpages on Chrome browser, but, I would like to turn off the page header option from printing dialog and keep only page footer, but on Chrome allow to turn on and off page header and footer together as [shown here](https://kb.whitman.edu/display/public/KB/How+to+Turn+off+Headers+and+Footers+when+Printing+from+a+webpage+or+Whitmail).

Is there any way I can do this in Chrome browser? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a trick in Chrome Browser, though I'm not sure it's the best solution.

By using the custom margin option in the printing dialog and dragging the top margin up a little bit.

[image: print dialog]

I'd still appreciate any better suggestions.